# Formating a MAC Address in WinForms

Tags: c#, formatting, mac-address

Using one of my WinForms applications, I need to display the MAC address of the computer's various network adapters in a textbox.

This code works fine in getting the string:

```
public string AdapterAddress(string criteria)
{
    adapteraddress = (from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                        where nic.Name == criteria
                        select nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()
                        ).First();
    return adapteraddress;
}
```

but it outputs as

```
003E4B880D01
```

as opposed to

```
00:3E:4B:88:0D:01
```

I'd love it if I could use this directly for a command line "ipconfig /all"

I know I need to do something with taking the individual bytes and then joining them with String.Join(":", blah blah) but I can't quite get it.

Here's my messy way to do it, but I feel like I might run into some unexpected problems with this later:

```
public string AdapterAddress(string criteria)
{
    adapteraddress = (from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                        where nic.Name == criteria
                        select nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()
                        ).First();

    var tempaddress = SplitMacAddress(adapteraddress);
    adapteraddress = tempaddress;
    return adapteraddress;
}

public string SplitMacAddress(string macadress)
{
    for (int Idx = 2; Idx <= 15; Idx += 3)
    {
        macadress = macadress.Insert(Idx, ":");
    }
    return macadress;
}
```

Is there a cleaner solution that I'm missing?

Comment: Just on a naming thing, I wouldn't name the function `SplitMacAddress`. This implies you are returning the individual bits. A better name might be `FormatMacAddress`. :) Sorry I can't help on the actual issue though.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your method?  What is wrong with `003E4B880D01` because that is the actual value.  The value isn't actually `00:3E:4B:88:0D:01` that is just pretty print for us humans.

Comment: Iterating feels like overkill and I'd love to add some checks later, if I could do it all in one area I feel like it becomes much more re-usable.

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting this, it's a legitimate question. You should probably lose the WinForms tag though, since the question itself has nothing to do with WinForms.

Comment: very true, wasn't intentionally trying to tag spam. it's certainly not an overly technical question but I'm trying to work on my readability and style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format a [`PhysicalAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress.aspx) instance as wished by taking the individual bytes and joining them in a string:

```
string formattedAddress = String.Join(":", 
    adapteraddress.GetAddressBytes()
       .Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))
       .ToArray()
    );
```

Note that you should leave out the `.ToString()` in your original query for this approach to work. Also, if you are on .NET 4, you can leave out the final `.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way: use BitConverter

var mac = BitConverter.ToString(nic.GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes()).Replace("-", ":");